# limit user access in multiple RODC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, authentication

I have a RODC and a RWDC.i prepopulate some password on RODC cache database. i already read this article [How’s User Authentication Working In A Site With A RODC?](http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=232)

I want to limit user access in multiple RODC.(for example user1 can not login to os in different RODC).

So i want to know is there is a way to limit user to login just from its RODC cache database not RWDC active directory?

**Original Comunication:**
[image]

**Can i do this?**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product doesn't have functionality to do what you're asking for using Read Only Domain Controllers (RoDC). You can control the password caching functionality of RoDCs but the ability for logons to be handled by a Read-Write Domain Controller (RWDC) can't be controlled.

It's unclear exactly what you're looking for. Perhaps you could elaborate about *why* you want this functionality.

You could make the "RoDC" machine in the example diagrams into a Domain Controller (DC) for a separate Active Directory (AD) Forest. That would cause it to handle all logon traffic and would prevent any implicit communication with the RWDCs in the other Forest. That's adding a lot of complexity, though.

In the end it's difficult to recommend anything to you without understanding why you want this.

Comment: exactly i have a one user (user1) in RWDC active directory my problem is here both clients in both RODCs can login to windows with "user1" account.i just want to assign "user1" to RODC A not to both RODC.is this possible?